# TF IDF weighed frequency scores in Test data, model trained using SVC

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, tf-idf

I am training a predictive model on text descriptions and a label corresponding to them. I am Using SVC to train the corpus of data with the tf idf weighted word frequencies. I want to understand if there's a new set of data(test, not using the train test split here) which i want to classify, Should it be vectorized using tf idf. If yes, should it be done on the Test data separately or along with Training data?

Answer (score 2):

Generally the TfIdf vectorizer is fit on the training data only and in order to get the test data in the same format we do the transform operation. This is primarily done to avoid data leakage. Please refer to [TfidfVectorizer: should it be used on train only or train+test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154660/tfidfvectorizer-should-it-be-used-on-train-only-or-traintest).

So first fit and transform your train data using tf-idf vectorizer and later on for any incoming dataset you could use the same tf-idf vectorizer for making the required transformation to tf-idf vectors.

you could do something like this,

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=101
)


transformer = TfidfTransformer()
x_train_tf = transformer.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test_tf = transformer.transform(x_test)
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response , Would it make sense to use the TfIdf scores of the training set on the test data
#### TfIdf scores of the training data####
tfidf = load("tfidf Combined_80perc_v7_df5.pickle") #to import TFIDF model
#####################
#Vectorize the dataframe to feed input data into model
test_features = tfidf.transform(df_check.Text_combined).toarray()

Comment: could you share your code snippet? That gives a clear picture to us.